# Laravel search for title and related tags

Tags: search, laravel, tags, many-to-many, eloquent

I want to search for posts by title and the related tags, which have a many-to-many relationship with posts. I came pretty far but theres something that botheres me. Here is my code:

```
$searchInput = Input::get('search');

$posts = Post::join('post_tag', 'post_tag.post_id','=','post.id')
             ->join('tag','tag.id','=','post_tag.tag_id')
             ->where('post.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchInput . '%')
             ->orWhere('tag.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchInput . '%')
             ->orderBy('post.created_at', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('post.id')
             ->with('tags')
             ->paginate(8);
```

This code (kind of) works. Lets say I have a post with the title `This is a test subject` and with the tags `CSS` and `HTML`.

- When I search for `test` or `subject`, I find the post, no problems here.
- When I search for `CSS` or `HTML`, I find the post, no problems here.

When I search for a combination of the two above (for example when I search for `test` and `CSS`, I find no post. Also, when I search for `CSS HTML` I don't get any results.

I hope somebody could help me out optimizing this search query, it gives me a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, this might be usefull for others. Here is the code:

```
$posts = Post::join('post_tag', 'post_tag.post_id','=','post.id')
         ->join('tag','tag.id','=','post_tag.tag_id')
         ->where('post.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchInput . '%')
         ->orWhereIn('tag.title', preg_split('/\s+/', trim($input['query']))) //The fix
         ->orderBy('post.created_at', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('post.id')
         ->with('tags')
         ->paginate(8);
```

There are multiple tags, the fix is to trim them and put them in an array. Then simply change `orWhere()` to `orWhereIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a query scope. And then use your relationships to query the rest...

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
  }

  public function scopeTitle($query, $title)
  {
    return $query->with('title', '=', $title);
  }
}
```

Then you could use the Model like this:

```
Post::title('Post Title')->tags();
```

This would get the post by the title and then all the tags associated with it if your Many To Many relationship is setup properly.

Comment: Yes I already have that working, that's not my problem. I want to search for all posts by title or related tags. Also, I think you ment whereTitle('title') :-).